# Testing Soap Service and XML message format

Tags: web-services, web-applications, soap, webservices-client

Hi i am newbie to SOAP Web service i am reading a book [Web Services Essentials(O'Reilly XML)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596002246).
i read a lot and feeling familiar with SOAP web services i run some examples.in this book chapter 6 there is a tool name as GLUE in which if we pass wsdl file url of web service and call a method on command line tool of SOAP web service then it give the output of web service .after some configuration changes it will give the message format passing between SOAP web service and SOAP client.can any one please suggest other alternate command line tools which give the xml messages that is passing between web services and client.please suggest some good tools for testing soap web services.

Answer (score 2):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a free **GUI** tool and it is great for testing web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl if you want to stick with command line utilities.

Example:

Create a request.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                   
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soap:Body>
       HERE COMES THE PAYLOAD
     </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>


curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
     -H "SOAPAction:http://www.my_amazing_webservice/DoSomethingAmazing"    \
     -d@request.xml    \
     http://www.my_amazing_webservice/amazing_stuff.asmx    \
     > output.xml
```

That is it.
Hope it helps.